# zsh completion : option zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes=long select to show the menu but bad foreground/background colors displayed for suggestions

Tags: zsh, iterm2, zshrc, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I have the following option for completion in my `~/.zshrc` :

```
# ZSH completion
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# Colorize completions using default `ls` colors.
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"

# Zsh reverse auto-completion
zmodload zsh/complist
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
# To get new binaries into PATH
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true

#zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort modification
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort date
zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes=long select

# Disable prompt disappearing on multi-lines
export COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="false"
```

My issue is about the displaying of suggestions when I do a "l+TAB" or a "cd Directory+TAB".

1. After a second and multiple others `TAB`, for the moment with the options above, everything seems to appear from the newest to the oldest and I can select from newest to oldest and the current selection is a white background with a black font (foreground)
2. But just a detail, I realize that when I do a first `cd + TAB`, the first selected directory is well in white background and black foreground (text) but just below, the second directory is also converted in green background and black font text (foreground) and I don't want it to be display like this, I just want it to display normally (I just want to display the current selection as "black on white" if this is a file and "black on green" if this is a directory, nothing else)

Here's an illustration of this issue :

[image: illustration of second suggestion converted]

If someone could indicate what's wrong with my options to prevent this behavior on the second suggested result after completion, this would be fine.

Comment: Are the permissions of `LAST_RESULTS-1-AOUT-2017` `777`? I think `LSCOLORS` defaults to showing something different if the directories writable or executable -- check `man ls` for the `LSCOLORS` section. You can override this coloring (see your `zstyle list-colors` option)